# Code misbehaving in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had to create tabs in my web page for which I used the code present in this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-use-css-and-jquery-to-hide-and-show-tab-content/

Now this code works beautifully in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't work appropriately in IE8. It displays the data in both the divisions instead of showing the data of the tab which is selected and hiding the other one. I have made a crude text based sample below. Hope it helps.

```
Tab1 | Tab2 |
--------------------------------------
            Page Heading

Content of tab 1


Content of tab 2

--------------------------------------
```

Hoping to receive your valuable inputs.

Comment: It's not my personal code, but belongs to my company. So I'll have to take a whole lot of permissions before I can post. The code is exactly as the one present in the link I posted though. I have not altered it.

Comment: Is your server on the local intranet?  If so, Internet explorer defaults to compatibility mode on the local internet, which may mess up certain rendering.  You need to use the X-UA-Compatible meta tag or header to make it render in standards mode.

Comment: I am running it on the localhost if that's what you are asking. Can you be more specific with the HTML tag. What exactly should I put there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it all worked out. I just had to replace the section tags in my HTML code with div tags. This is because HTML 4 does not support section tags.